# Error while creating asset using Azure Media Services REST API and PHP

Tags: php, rest, azure, azure-media-services

I get a HTTP Code 301 error while executing php code for creating an asset:

```
 public function request($arrData = array()){
            $ch = curl_init();
            $arrHeader = array(
                'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->strToken,

            );
        echo 'Call API:'.$this->strUrl."\n";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->strUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrHeader);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        if (!empty($data)){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->generateData($arrData));
        }
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
       The value of strUrl is: https://media.windows.net/API/Assets
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you are using the right URL. This one works for me.

https://wamsbluclus001rest-hs.cloudapp.net/API/

Answer (score 0):

The issue here in PHP is that it looks like you are not following the redirect that happens when connecting to the API.  It's documented in MSDN docs for the REST API.  Take a look at this MSDN reference doc that explains how to follow the redirects:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129576.aspx

> **Connecting to the Media Services URI** The root URI for Media Services is https://media.windows.net/API/. You should initially
>   connect to this URI, and if you get a 301 redirect back in response,
>   you should make subsequent calls to the new URI. In addition, do not
>   use any auto-redirect/follow logic in your requests. HTTP verbs and
>   request bodies will not be forwarded to the new URI.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you'll find a working example of the redirect handling here:
http://createassettask.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21236#458379